# difference between symbol-value and eval

Tags: elisp-macros, symbols, eval

```
(defmacro ek/bind-evil-keys-map (state keymap key-fn-list)
  (let* ((key-fns (symbol-value key-fn-list))
       (body (mapcar
              (lambda (pair)
                `(evil-define-key ,state ,keymap (kbd ,(car pair)) ,(cdr pair)))
              key-fns)))
  `(progn ,@body))
)

(defvar motion-keys
  '(
    ("C-o" . 'ek/xref-go-back)
    ("<C-i>" . 'ek/xref-go-forward)
    ))

(ek/bind-evil-keys-map '(normal motion) 'global motion-keys)
```

Here I'm using `symbol-value`,
I read macro doesn't evaluate arguments (but function does) so, I tried `(eval key-fn-list)`.

But it seems it is not same as `(symbol-value key-fn-list)`.
So what is the difference?

Comment: FWIW, you should not `eval` / `symbol-value` a symbol coming from a macro form during macro-expansion. (Actually you can, but you may get unexpected results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to evaluate the arguments, then you shouldn’t be writing a macro. Just write this as an ordinary function.

To answer your question, simply use `C-h f` to look up the help for both `eval` and `symbol-value`. You will soon see the difference; `eval` evaluates arbitrary code, while `symbol-value` takes a symbol and returns the value of the variable named by that symbol.

Edit:

I checked the documentation of `evil-define-key` (I don’t use evil-mode myself), and I have no idea why you are writing this macro. `evil-define-key` already lets you bind an arbitrary number of keys. Your code could just be written like this:

```lisp
(evil-define-key '(normal insert) global-map
    "C-o"   'ek/xref-go-back
    "<C-i>" 'ek/xref-go-forward)
```

You really should read the documentation of these things using `C-h i`. It will save you a lot of wasted work.

Comment: I read function evaluates the argument (whereas macro doesnt) , here `evaluate` is not the same as `eval` ? is it actually `symbol-value` ?

Comment: I tried to not use macro so hard (because it was so hard to use it for the first time) but I couldn't make a function that can take a symbol and forward it to a macro here (evil-define-key is the macro)

Comment: “Evaluate” _always_ means `eval`. If `eval` sees a symbol, it will call `symbol-value`. If it sees `(+ 2 2)`, it will call `(apply #'+ 2 2)`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

(Here I don't discuss the reasonableness of OP evaluating a symbol from a macro form during macro-expansion.  
 You have your own idea, either way, I can't stop you from doing it.)

You should always use `symbol-value` when possible.  
[GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual, 10.5 Eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval.html):

> Often **`eval` is not needed** and something else should be used instead.
> For example, **to get the value of a variable**, while `eval` works, **`symbol-value` is preferable**;

Avoid using `eval` when possible.  
See also [“A mutable object stops being mutable if it is part of an expression that is evaluated.”](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/75802/39388).  
[GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual, 2.9 Mutability](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mutability.html):

> A mutable object stops being mutable if it is part of an expression that is evaluated.
> For example:
>
> ```lisp
> (let* ((x (list 0.5))
>        (y (eval (list 'quote x))))
>   (setcar x 1.5) ;; The program should not do this.
>   y)
> ```
>
> Although the list `(0.5)` was mutable when it was created, it should not have been changed via `setcar` **because it was given to `eval`**.